# DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Ajax error. Shiny App in R

Tags: r, shiny

I received such an error when, in creating shiny app in R with DataTables packages, I pressed button that should sort columns in the table output.
Any idea how to fix this problem?
The solution for this problem should be explained here http://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/7 but I don't know how to translate this to R shiny language and syntax.

Comment: FWIW you have more than enough rep on this website to know that you should [make your questions reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)...

Comment: did you just upgrade shiny?

Comment: This is issue #266 with `DT` on Github. Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/40086898/4606130

Answer (score 1):

Try converting your table data to data frame, as in:

```
output$mytable <- renderDataTable({
df <- getGAData(input$site, input$startDate, input$endDate)
as.data.frame(goalConvByHour(df, input$daysSelected))},
options = list(paging = FALSE, searching = FALSE))
```