# DataTable warning table ajax error for some people but not all with shiny

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I recieved such error when, in created shiny app in R with DataTables packages in my mobile and one laptop. However, it didn't throw error with other laptops, Same code was working yesterday, and day before yesterday. I haven't changed code, but it is throwing error.

Why there is problem with some devices but not all devices. I used other devices, those devices are not throwing error.

Any idea how to fix this problem? The solution for this problem should be explained here http://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/7

What is issue ?

Following is thrown error as follows:

> DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Ajax error. For more
>   information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

Comment: I experience same problem with shiny app using DT package. Only some clients are exposed which is strange and on some others error appears non deterministically.

Comment: Did you find a fix for this? I encounter the same issues..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am also suffering. Please take a look at the discussion of this [issue #269 on Github](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/269).

It seems to be a problem post version 0.1 where you need to "flatten" variables using `as.numeric`.

**ISSUE**

Example and solution given by **XD-DENG** was and to quote them:

"The error is gone when I use

```
temp <- tapply(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Species, mean)
  result <- data.frame(species = names(temp),
                       mean = as.numeric(temp))
  return(result)
```

instead of:

```
temp <- tapply(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Species, mean)
  result <- data.frame(species = names(temp),
                       mean = temp)
  return(result)
```

The main difference is whether the column mean has additional attribution, dimension. This is what caused the error.

But it's still weird given version 0.1 of DT works perfectly on both."

**PATCH**

@yihui has pushed a fix for this to the dev version so please try update your `DT` package. (You can use package devtools to install from github `devtools::install_github('rstudio/DT')`)

I hope this fixes this intermittent error.

Comment: I updated to latest version 0.2.10 still facing this issue if I ping directly to public IP to my aws instance I didn't face any error only if I'm visiting the website address and that too if ping request is from India ( server hosted in Sydney) 

instance is behind load balancer and it forwards port 80 to 3838

Answer (score 2):

I just explicitly made as.numeric() to all numeric columns within my data.frame (though they are already numeric when I do str()) and the problem is gone.