# DT table notification pops up frequently

Tags: shiny

I have a shiny application where there is a DT table. The app is all fine but most of the time, i see this notification popping up. Not sure what it is. Sometimes, it does not. Can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: Hi, it will be easier to help you with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Oh. But it is a huge code. Is it not possible based on your experience what might be the issue :) ?

Comment: The point of making a smaller example is to reduce the number possible causes of the bug. It happens a lot that I find the solution to the problem simply by preparing a very simple example to post on StackOverflow. So you should really do your best to make a small reproducible example. Also, I don't remember having seen this error before so no idea where it might come from

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36266729/datatable-warning-table-ajax-error-for-some-people-but-not-all-with-shiny

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DataTable warning table ajax error for some people but not all with shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36266729/datatable-warning-table-ajax-error-for-some-people-but-not-all-with-shiny)

Answer (score 0):

Using client side processing in `DT::renderDataTable` helped solve this issue for me
https://rstudio.github.io/DT/server.html

```
DT::renderDataTable(iris, server = FALSE)
```